# Cannot find name 'FunctionName'

Tags: angular

I get the following error message, but the function obviously exists:

**Cannot find name 'onCreateServer'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.onCreateServer'?**

This is my TypeScript code.

```ts
onCreateServer() {
    //Do something...
}

onKeyPress(event: any) {
    if(event.keyCode==13) {
        onCreateServer();  //<--error comes from this..
    }
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```html
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="serverName"
    (keyup)="onKeyPress($event)">

<p>{{serverName}}</p>

<button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        [disabled]="!allowNewServer"
        (click)="onCreateServer()">Add Server</button>
```

Comment: Yes, you *did* mean the instance member 'this.onCreateServer'. Add the `this.`.

Comment: call like `this.onCreateServer()` insted of 'onCreateServer()'.

Comment: @switch agree with you I am also learning and faced these kinds of situations many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be like as following..

```
onCreateServer() {
    //Do something...
}

onKeyPress(event: any) {
    if(event.keyCode==13) {
        this.onCreateServer();  //<--error comes from this..
    }
}
```

Comment: what I don't get, is I actually tried that based on it's message in the past and it wasn't working, so I found a different way to do it..  Now it's working..   WTH!!

Comment: May be you have tried in some diff way. Did you use `this` in function declaration instead of the function call.